# SwiftUI OAuth failing to redirect

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, oauth

I am trying to implement the callback from a redirect URI for OAuth in SwiftUI. I am currently using BetterSafariView from GitHub, and everything works fine until I input my credentials in Safari, where I go to my redirect URI, however, the callback does not work... I must be missing something here.

```
readyPageBody()
        .webAuthenticationSession(isPresented: $startingWebAuthenticationSession)
    {
        WebAuthenticationSession(
            url: URL(string: 
            "URL&redirect_uri=https://stockorbit.app&response_type=code")!,
            callbackURLScheme: "stockorbit")
        {
            callbackURL, error in
            print("inside callback..")
            print(callbackURL, error)
        }.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession(false)


    }
```

When I complete the OAuth, I get redirected to StockOrbit.app, where the code is in the URL. On the top left, the cancel button is there, and never Done. In addition, Safari doesn't close out back to the app... What am I missing here?